I cannot ask anymore questions on askbuntu, it won't let me. It seems I've been banned
So I'm currently having an issue with Ubuntu and I need to ask for help from the Linux experts but it won't let me ask anymore questions (it seems I've essentially been banned from askubuntu) Who put these restrictions on my account of 8 years? I've been a member here for 8 years. This is so unfair. I'm on the verge of crying.
Who did this to my account? Why?
Please can you fix my account? Thank you.
Edit: It's been brought to my attention that the restrictions were automatically put on my account cause I had 2 questions closed as duplicates. Ok, so I got 2 questions closed as duplicates, so does this mean that I should have my account banned?
Please change this so this doesn't happen to any other accounts going forward. I only come to askubuntu when I need help. I'm innocent. Please change the rules of the website so this doesn't happen to anyone else. This should have never happened to me.
Edit: Why are you doing this to me? What did I do to deserve this kind of treatment? I am having a bug with Ubuntu and I need help from the Linux experts, but I can't ask anymore questions, why are you doing this to me? Please I'm on the verge of crying, why are you doing this to me?
I feel like I'm being bullied. Why are you doing this to me?


As a suggestion, try answering some questions as well as asking. It might help. (I'm not a moderator. This is just a suggestion.)

@TRiG  "try answering some questions as well as asking" I CAN'T ASK QUESTIONS. I have been banned from asking questions, do you understand? And I can't answer questions cause I'm a newbie. I am a newbie, I can't answer questions. I come to askubuntu cause I'm a newbie. I come to askubuntu cause I need help cause I'm a newbie. Yeah I'm not a computer expert, I'm a newbie. I'll always be a Linux newbie, I'll never fully understand Linux. I'm not a coder, I'm not a programmer, I AM A NEWBIE.

@SpaceX read the linked duplicate. Note that Ask Ubuntu is not the only support site out there.

@ThomasWard I've done nothing wrong!!!! Why is my account banned?????
